# Фоновая служба не работает в фоне.

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, service, gps

Здравствуйте, есть фоновая служба которая ловит gps, и после отправляет на сервер. На эмуляторе после закрытия приложения, логи идут, координаты посылает. На реальном девайсе ( в фоне) не работает когда закрываешь приложение. В чем может быть причина?

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final String TAG = LocationService.class.getName();

private Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

public boolean canGetLocation = false;

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long TIME_BY_UPDATES = 30 * 1000;

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

  public LocationService(Context context) {
     this.mContext = context;
     getLocation();
  }

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Log.i("GPS", "from gps");
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            TIME_BY_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.i("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            // MyApp.getServerCommunicatorClass().sendUserCoordinates();
                            Log.i("sending", "myMethodWorks");

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // second get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.i("GPS", "from net");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        TIME_BY_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.i("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //MyApp.getServerCommunicatorClass().sendUserCoordinates();
                        Log.i("sending+Net", "myMethodWorks");

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    //do something
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Написать код для метода

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Написать код для метода

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Написать код для метода

}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationService.this);
    }
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.mContext = this; // you prolly dont need this at all and can just use "this"
    getLocation();

    Log.i("LocationService ", "служба создана");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Служба запущена",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("LocationService ", "служба запущена");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Служба остановлена",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public static boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
    Log.i("LocationService ", " is running");
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (LocationService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getName();

    public static String ALARM_EVENT() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    String str=
                    ServerCommunicator.sendUserCoordinates();
    Log.i("TAG","alarm/coord= "+str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("Alarm", "ALARM_EVENT: send coords");
            }

        }).start();

        return null;
    }

    public static final int ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC = 3;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Alarm", "Alarm received: " + intent.getAction());

        try {
            setAlarm(context);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context) throws IOException {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ALARM_EVENT()), 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * ALARM_INTERVAL_SEC, pi);
        Log.i("Alarm", "setAlarm");
    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) throws IOException {
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ALARM_EVENT()), 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }

    public static boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
        Log.i("Alarm ", " is running");
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (Alarm.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

}

Вот вызов:

```
    MainActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_start);

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.Alarm.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,30);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,30*1000,alarmIntent);
```

Comment: где у вас прописан `stopService()`?

Comment: извините, по описанию невозможно представить ваш код... Не могли бы вы его выложить?

Comment: @monomi этого метода в коде вообще нет

Comment: @metalurgus вот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос разрешился добавлением двух строк:

```
startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Полный код:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.user_start);

startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.Alarm.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 30 * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```